# get laravel eloquent model relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

is there any way to get the defined relationships in eloquent model. I have a situation where I need to get the model relationships so I can update all other eloquent models that relies on a specific id before delete it

Comment: can you input your code please, so we can see an example.. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```
 public function getRelations()
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no unified method to iterate over all registered relationships of a class. You can, however, access all the currently loaded relationships of a model instance (via the `->relations` attribute or the `getRelations()` method), but that's not what you're up to. I'd suggest you take a look at laravel's [documentation on inserting and updating relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models). So far that's the best laravel provides out of the box, the rest is developing approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$model->getRelations()
```

function to get all relations

Also refer below link for details https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_getRelations